# React render recursively is very slow for many levels, is Parallelism available?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, components

I have a tree with 12 levels and contains a lot of branches. and I'm rendering them recursively, the question if each node has many branches. Can I render each branch in **parallel**?

Parallel: no need to wait for other branches to rendered in the same node

PS: If I can't do the parallel, Can I update the dom after each vertex, so no need to wait until all vertices are rendered?

PS: I'm rendering 600 components in 12 levels, which leads to browser freezing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a experimental feature at this momment, but it is not available yet.
https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html

what I would probably do, would be to create asynchronous components and improve the code with code splitting.

Components will be loaded according to their own time

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazyload